# jQuery toggle 3 Div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, switch-statement, toggle

I wanna toggle 3 div.
In the start situation I have the first div that is not trigger able for the clic because its ID.
When I click the second or third div (triggered), the DIV clicked have to become unclickable and the others 2 clickable.

I attach my live example:

http://jsfiddle.net/YV3V5/

HTML:

```
<div id = "not-selectable" class = "btn1">Div 1</div>
<div id = "selectable" class = "btn2">Div 2</div>
<div id = "selectable" class = "btn3">Div 3</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
$( "#selectable" ).click(function(e) {


    var className = $(this).attr('class');

    alert(className);

    if (className == "btn1") {
        $("btn1").attr("selectable","not-selectable");
        $("btn2").attr("not-selectable","selectable");
        $("btn3").attr("not-selectable","selectable");   
    } else if (className == "btn2") {
        $("btn2").attr("selectable","not-selectable");
        $("btn1").attr("not-selectable","selectable");
        $("btn3").attr("not-selectable","selectable");   
    } else if (className == "btn3") {
        $("btn3").attr("selectable","not-selectable");
        $("btn1").attr("not-selectable","selectable");
        $("btn2").attr("not-selectable","selectable");   
    }

});
```

In this situation when I click the second DIV, it should became unclickable....but nothing happens.

Thanks for you're help!

Comment: attribute ID must be unique there are two same value of ID is selectable

Comment: $( "div" ).click(function(e) try this one

Comment: You wrote "unclickable", but all your selectors say "not selectable". you meant, that your divs should be non-selectable or non-clickable?? if non-clicable then could you explain WHY do you need it? What SHOULD NOT happen when element is clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several errors in your code. The most important being that IDs should be unique.  Secondly you are trying to assign values to attributes "selectable" and "not-selectable". These attributes do not exist.

If you lay out your markup correctly, you could do this pretty simple. I would suggest something like this:

HTML

```
<div class="buttons">
    <div class="button">Div 1</div>
    <div class="button selectable">Div 2</div>
    <div class="button selectable">Div 3</div>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$( ".buttons" ).on("click",".selectable",function(e) {
    $('.button').addClass('selectable');
    $(this).removeClass('selectable');
});
```

**[Can be tested here](http://jsfiddle.net/NP2yM/)**

(I've added a parent element to simplify event delegation in jQuery.)

Answer (score 0):

there is no attribute called selectable for html tags.

when you write  $("btn3").attr("selectable","not-selectable"); it means set the selectable attribute of btn3 to value 'not-selectable'.

also as btn3 is a class you should have written $('.btn3') instead of $('btn3')

Answer (score 0):

**WORKING DEMO** http://jsfiddle.net/YV3V5/23/

There was a lot wrong with your code :

1) using duplicate id's : Id's must be unique , one per page. Classes do not have to be unique. So I changed around your id's and classes.

2) you should change classes with addClass/removeClass/or toggleClass

3) you shouldn't use a class your removing as the trigger of the click function, so I gave them all a same class of `btn`.

html :

```
<div id="btn1" class="not-selectable btn">Div 1</div>
<div id="btn2" class="selectable btn">Div 2</div>
<div id="btn3" class="selectable btn">Div 3</div>
```

css *I added background of blue for selectable and red for not-selectable so easier to visualize what's happening*:

```
.selectable {
    background: blue;
}
.not-selectable {
    background: red;
}
```

jquery :

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(".btn").click(function (e) {

        var id = $(this).attr('id');

        if (id == "btn1") {
            $("#btn1").removeClass("selectable").addClass("not-selectable");
            $("#btn2").addClass("selectable").removeClass("not-selectable");
            $("#btn3").addClass("selectable").removeClass("not-selectable");
        } else if (id == "btn2") {
            $("#btn2").removeClass("selectable").addClass("not-selectable");
            $("#btn1").addClass("selectable").removeClass("not-selectable");
            $("#btn3").addClass("selectable").removeClass("not-selectable");
        } else if (id == "btn3") {
            $("#btn3").removeClass("selectable").addClass("not-selectable");
            $("#btn1").addClass("selectable").removeClass("not-selectable");
            $("#btn2").addClass("selectable").removeClass("not-selectable");
        }

    });

});
```

Answer (score -1):

.attr() sets the attribute to the tags. So like you would get `<div non-selectable='selectable'>` for that code. Here is the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/attr/). I would use .removeClass() and .addClass() though there might be a more efficient way.